# Add Data Dynamically to Framework7 Smart select?

Tags: html-framework-7

I'm trying to add data dynamically to a Smart select in Framework7, but I can't get this working.

I'm trying to make a filter with smart selects.

I have three smart selects: car brand, engine, and amount of doors.

Once the brand is selected, the next smart select should be dynamically filled with content.

If one engine is selected, the amount of doors should be dynamically filled.

I failed at the point to add data dynamically.

I have a jsFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/o2ejupu1/669/

```
 var app = new Framework7({
    root: '#app',
    theme: 'auto',
    smartSelect: {
        pageTitle: 'Select Option',
        openIn: 'popup',
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            carBrands: ["honda", "bmw", "ford", "vw"]
        };
    },
    methods: {
        createSelect: function () {
            let carsSelect = document.getElementById("cars");
            app.data.carBrands.forEach(addCars);
            carsSelect.innerHTML = carsSelect.innerHTML + "<option value=" + index + ">" + item + "</option>";
        }
    },
    routes: [{
        path: '/about/',
        content: `
        <div class="page">
          <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
                <div class="left">
                <a href="#" class="link back">
                  <i class="icon icon-back"></i>
                  <span class="ios-only">Back</span>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="title">About</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="page-content">
            <li>
  <a onclick="app.methods.createSelect()" class="item-link smart-select smart-select-init" data-open-in="popup"  data-searchbar="true" data-searchbar-placeholder="Search car">
    <select name="car" id="carsSelect" multiple>
    </select>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title">Car</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
          </div>
        </div>
      `
    }]
});

var viewMain = app.views.create('.view-main');
var smartSelect = app.smartSelect.create({ /* parameters */ });
```

Has somebody done something like this before, or is here a better way to do this?

Comment: i think you need to describe how it fails in more detail to let potential helpers better understand the problem.

Comment: did you finally solve this issue. I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have to use the smart-select auto init because it will initialize with the current select options placed in the select, what i would suggest is you populate your DOM first with the initial values (cars) then create a smart select like:

```
  data: function () {
        return {
            carBrands: ["honda", "bmw", "ford", "vw"]
        };
    },
    methods: {
        createSelect: function () {
            let carsSelect = document.getElementById("cars");
            app.data.carBrands.forEach(addCars);
            carsSelect.innerHTML = carsSelect.innerHTML + "<option value=" + index + ">" + item + "</option>";

            //after creating the DOM then you can call in the create smart-select
           app.smartSelect.create('.smart-select')
        }
    }
```

NB: **remove the smart-select-init class** in the template when loaded so that you initialise the select on the fly

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it truely makes sense to init the smartselect in the funciton where i do a get request for example. I've updated the jsfiddle, but it still does't work. It says the method which i call is not reachable. https://jsfiddle.net/o2ejupu1/672/

Comment: the reason why i think the "called method is unreachable"  is because when when you declared `smartSelect` you were more of overriding the default one so it might be failing to get the `.create()` method of the `smartSelect` object. Find a way of separating the 2. 

The logic is like when you initialized `data`, its not an F7 default but you could access it as a new variable in the script. It becomes more of a local variable than global